How to choose k grid and projections in wannier90
I am trying to calculate the Berry curvature of a material using Wannier90, and I have a few questions:
I have frozen bands below the Fermi level (using dis_froz_max) and have chosen dis_win_max as 30 eV. However, after calculating the Wannier functions within this energy window, I am still not getting a good band structure (at least near to the band structure given by DFT). How can I verify whether my Wannier functions are correct?
Initially, I selected the valence orbitals of the constituent atoms for the projections.
Thanks in advance
